How can I rewrite URLs for certain specific paths with Caddy?
When on my local environment, I want to serve the media files of my dev site from the live version.
With Apache, this was done like so :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testsite\.local$
  RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://prodsite.org/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

So, when the URL contains /uploads/, the domain should be changed from devsite.local to prodsite.org.
For example :
https://testsite.local/wp-content/uploads/logo.webp
becomes
https://prodsite.org/wp-content/uploads/logo.webp
How can this be done with Caddy ?
